# iTunes App Store Error "This build is invalid."

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect, ios-frameworks

I am uploading new build in app store.after successfully updated build i am getting this mail from apple and i am getting error "This build is invalid."
i am not getting exact issue.please suggest me what i am doing wrong.

Dear developer,

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "Eventure Everywhere". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:

This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for /Payload/Eventure.app/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework is missing or could not be read.

Invalid Bundle - The bundle at '/Payload/Eventure.app/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework' does not contain a bundle executable.

This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for /Payload/Eventure.app/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework is missing or could not be read.

Invalid Bundle - The bundle at '/Payload/Eventure.app/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework' does not contain a bundle executable.

This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for /Payload/Eventure.app/Accelerate.framework is missing or could not be read.

Invalid Bundle - The bundle at '/Payload/Eventure.app/Accelerate.framework' does not contain a bundle executable.

Invalid Bundle Structure - - The framework at '/Payload/Eventure.app/Accelerate.framework' is not permitted. Do not include platform frameworks in your app.

This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for /Payload/Eventure.app/CoreData.framework is missing or could not be read.

Invalid Bundle - The bundle at '/Payload/Eventure.app/CoreData.framework' does not contain a bundle executable.

Invalid Bundle Structure - - The framework at '/Payload/Eventure.app/CoreData.framework' is not permitted. Do not include platform frameworks in your app.

This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for /Payload/Eventure.app/Foundation.framework is missing or could not be read.

Invalid Bundle - The bundle at '/Payload/Eventure.app/Foundation.framework' does not contain a bundle executable.

Invalid Bundle Structure - - The framework at '/Payload/Eventure.app/Foundation.framework' is not permitted. Do not include platform frameworks in your app.

This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for /Payload/Eventure.app/MessageUI.framework is missing or could not be read.

Invalid Bundle - The bundle at '/Payload/Eventure.app/MessageUI.framework' does not contain a bundle executable.

Invalid Bundle Structure - - The framework at '/Payload/Eventure.app/MessageUI.framework' is not permitted. Do not include platform frameworks in your app.

This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for /Payload/Eventure.app/MobileCoreServices.framework is missing or could not be read.

Invalid Bundle - The bundle at '/Payload/Eventure.app/MobileCoreServices.framework' does not contain a bundle executable.

Invalid Bundle Structure - - The framework at '/Payload/Eventure.app/MobileCoreServices.framework' is not permitted. Do not include platform frameworks in your app.

This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for /Payload/Eventure.app/OpenGLES.framework is missing or could not be read.

Invalid Bundle - The bundle at '/Payload/Eventure.app/OpenGLES.framework' does not contain a bundle executable.

Invalid Bundle Structure - - The framework at '/Payload/Eventure.app/OpenGLES.framework' is not permitted. Do not include platform frameworks in your app.

This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for /Payload/Eventure.app/QuartzCore.framework is missing or could not be read.

Invalid Bundle - The bundle at '/Payload/Eventure.app/QuartzCore.framework' does not contain a bundle executable.

Invalid Bundle Structure - - The framework at '/Payload/Eventure.app/QuartzCore.framework' is not permitted. Do not include platform frameworks in your app.

This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for /Payload/Eventure.app/StoreKit.framework is missing or could not be read.

Invalid Bundle - The bundle at '/Payload/Eventure.app/StoreKit.framework' does not contain a bundle executable.

Invalid Bundle Structure - - The framework at '/Payload/Eventure.app/StoreKit.framework' is not permitted. Do not include platform frameworks in your app.

This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for /Payload/Eventure.app/SystemConfiguration.framework is missing or could not be read.

Invalid Bundle - The bundle at '/Payload/Eventure.app/SystemConfiguration.framework' does not contain a bundle executable.

Invalid Bundle Structure - - The framework at '/Payload/Eventure.app/SystemConfiguration.framework' is not permitted. Do not include platform frameworks in your app.

This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for /Payload/Eventure.app/UIKit.framework is missing or could not be read.

Invalid Bundle - The bundle at '/Payload/Eventure.app/UIKit.framework' does not contain a bundle executable.

Invalid Bundle Structure - - The framework at '/Payload/Eventure.app/UIKit.framework' is not permitted. Do not include platform frameworks in your app.

Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Regards,

The App Store team

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed the issue.simply removed all framework and agains add in your Project.its working.

Thank You